# Tools and ways to find possible problems with C source code

Tags: c

**EDIT** Thanks to all for your input. I guess my question was just a little to fuzzy. I have thus accepted a sensible answer and opted for 2 hours of stubborn exit(9) debugging and found, or at least removed two bugs, and am now proud to have solved a difficult riddle... ;-)

I've invested a great deal of time for a problem solution on http://www.spoj.pl , and the program works locally with all the testsamples I have created myself, as well as with those from the problem description.

However, the program aborts with `SIGSEGV` on the server. There, I have uploaded it with `C99 strict` language option selected.

**EDIT**: Let me point out clearly again that there's absolutely no hint as to how the `SIGSEGV` occured. The only information that I have is that it occurred at all. Thanks to @Oli Charlesworth for pointing this out.

Locally, I have compiled with both

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -o prog prog.c
```

and

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -m32 -std=c99 -o prog prog.c
```

and everything works fine. The 64bit version was compiled on a regular Debian squeeze amd64 system, the `-m32` version on a regular Debian Lenny amd64 system (but only because Squeeze is broken with `-m32`).

`valgrind -v` is also perfectly fine with my program.

All my `malloc`'s and `calloc`'s make sure the return value is nonzero. Except for `tsearch`, I am not using anything but the very common standard functions.

I would like to collect some pointers as to how I could find out what the problem is. (If there is anything but assuming the input having unexpected properties)

Comment: Can you see output from the program before it crashes on the server? i.e. would you be able to add in some `printf()`s to see where the problem occurs?

Comment: @Hgeg: No, is the a way I can use it to my advantage when the program runs fine on my system?

Comment: @e.James: No, unfortunately the only feedback I can get is "crashed with `SIGSEGV`"

Comment: I assume you have already dived into the SPOJ forums? I found two links: [one](http://www.spoj.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5483) and [two](http://www.spoj.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5337) which could be useful.

Comment: In particular, one of the comments on that second link recommends using a different server (http://ideone.com/), which supposedly provides better debugging tools

Comment: @e.James: That doesn't help as I don't have the input that the program gets on spoj.pl

Comment: If your code even contemplates the possibility that a long may be 64 bits, it's probably wrong on the SPOJ hardware. If your code only uses explicitly sized types, so that's not a possible cause, you can try to locate the place of the `SIGSEGV` by inserting an `exit(9)` (or whatever your favourite number `!= SIGSEGV` is) at varying places (as a last desperate measure, fine-tooth your code before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an environment with such limited feedback, one tool that you can use is what I would call a "binary search" for the source of the problem:

Start by uploading the simplest "hello world" program that will run on the server, and verify that it does not crash. Then, start adding in chunks of your code until the program *does* crash. When it does, backtrack and add smaller chunks of code until you have narrowed it down to a particular piece of code that is responsible for the crash.

Once you have it narrowed down, you can try re-writing the troublesome block of code, or look for a different way to accomplish the right result.

Comment: +1.  But I guess the OP is asking "what can I do in my local environment to prove that I'm not relying on undefined behaviour, etc.?".

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: It sounds to me like the program checks out fine in the local environment. Searching for a non-reproducible bug in a system that does not exhibit the problem would be an excercise in frustration!

Comment: Of course!  But sometimes that's the situation you find yourself in.  Perhaps you have a slightly different version of GCC, etc.  But the cause is almost certainly down to some unintentional reliance on undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with "-g".

Run:

`ulimit -c`

If it returns 0, or a small number of bytes, then type in the following:

`ulimit -c unlimited`

This allows cores of unlimited size to be dumped.  You will want to examine your core dump to see where the segmentation fault occurred.  Run gdb on the core file to find out this information.  It will point you to the line that caused the core dump, and possibly give you more information as to why it seg faulted.

See this link for information on examining core dumps with gdb:

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_38.html

The link provides much more information.